# Handle github.GithubException.GithubException: error

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I have a function like this to create a github repo and return it.

```
def CreateGitHubRepo(token, repo_name):
    # instantiate github account
    g = Github(token)
    # create authenticated user 
    authed_user = g.get_user()

    # create a new repo
    repo = authed_user.create_repo(repo_name)
    return repo
```

However if a repo already exists with the same name I get an error raised `github.GithubException.GithubException: 422 {"message": "Repository creation failed.", "errors": [{"resource": "Repository", "code": "custom", "field": "name", "message": "name already exists on this account"}], "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"}`

My question is how could I handle this in my script to catch this error and move forward e.g.

```
    try:
        NewRepo = CreateGitHubRepo(token, repo_name)
        print("Created New Git Repo: %s" % repo_name)
        print(NewRepo)
    except GithubException as err:
        print('test')
```

I've tried all the ways I can think of to get the except to catch that error and I'm a little confused.

Comment: What error you are getting when you try to catch with `except GithubException as err:`?

Answer (score 0):

Answer, I wasn't importing the github module as desired.
I had
`from github import Github`
so wasn't including the GithubException class.

Lesson, check the imports are doing what you expect.